# How do you access the Pine Script Code Behind a public Indicator in TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, indicator

Wondering how I can access the Pine Script code behind a public indicator which I have added to a chart in TradingView?

Wanting to see exactly what is going on "under the hood".

I have a free account (if that affects anything)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Show Source Code` button right next to the script you want to see the source code of.

[image]

However, the author may choose not to share the source code. In that case, you cannot see the source code. When someone publishes a script, they have the following options:

[image]

- **Open:** Everyone can see the source code and apply it to a chart.
- **Protected:** No one can see the source code but everyone can apply it
  to a chart.
- **Invite Only:** Only those you give permission to access to the script can apply it
  to a chart. No one can see the source code.

Currently, only *premium* users can publish a script as *invite only*.